# Code Signing with Visual Studio and Version Control

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, code-signing

I am developing a windows driver and have correctly configured the code signing certificate in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

The problem, however, is that Visual Studio stores the code signing properties of the driver project (and driver package project) in the `*.vcxproj.user` file instead of the `*.vcxproj` file.

The content looks like this and appears multiple times:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Win7 Debug|x64'">
    <DebuggerFlavor>DbgengRemoteDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
    <SignMode>ProductionSign</SignMode>
    <ProductionCertificate>..certificate details here..</ProductionCertificate>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The problem is, that the `*.vcxproj.user` file is not (and should not) be under version control, which means that every contributer as well as Jenkins has to set up driver signing on its own.

What is the reason behind this behaviour and how can I change this so that these settings are also under version control?

Comment: I just ran into this issue and it took me a while to track down, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, no solution yet.